# Taking in two strings and returns a new string with the occurrences of the second string removed (No if statements)

Tags: java

I'm not asking for an answer, I'm just looking for a hint. This is for a homework assignment and I have to write a method that takes in two strings and returns a new string, it has to look like the original string, but with occurrences of the second string removed. I can't use if statements.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        System.out.println(without("operation", "ra"));
        System.out.println(without("checkers", "ers"));
        System.out.println(without("checkers", "ch"));
    }

    public static String without(String x, String y) {
        int indexNumb = x.lastIndexOf(y);
        int lastIndex = x.length();
        String firstWord = x.substring(0, indexNumb);
        String secondHalf = x.substring(indexNumb + 2, lastIndex);
        return firstWord + secondHalf;
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
opetion
checks
eckers
```

I'm supposed to get:

```
opetion
check
eckers
```

Comment: something like `x.replaceAll(y, "");` should work

Comment: We never learned that command so it wouldnt get credit

Comment: It's very hard for us to know what part of the `String` class you have or haven't learned.

Comment: 1) Split the string on the occurance of `y` into an array. 2) join all the parts together into a single string again

Comment: we learned Making a string, index, char, charAt, substring, lastIndexOf, length

Comment: Lino we havent done arrays yet. I can only solve this using string methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following line of code:

> ```
> String secondHalf = x.substring(indexNumb + 2, lastIndex);
> ```

you make the assumption that `y` (i.e. the string to be removed) is two characters long. This assumption holds for your first and third testcase, but not for the second, which is why you get an extra letter in your output.

Use the following replacement instead:

```
String secondHalf = x.substring(indexNumb + y.length(), lastIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be `x.replaceAll(y, "");`

In case you did not learn that command yet, or you are not allowed to use that command:
Your solution is pretty good so far.

```
String secondHalf = x.substring(indexNumb + 2, lastIndex);
```

You are cutting two letters out of the String. This works fine for second strings like "ra" or "ch".
To make it work for any second string, just replace the `2` by `y.length()`.

```
String secondHalf = x.substring(indexNumb + y.length(), lastIndex);
```

Comment: This still fails, if `y` is not a part of `x`!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using String .replace function. String replace function takes two arguments. First is the string pattern to be replaced and second what to replace it with. (Not submitting full answer as requested)

Answer (score 0):

You say this is a homework assignment. Then you should be allowed to take a look at the javadoc of String and find a method that fits the requirement (like mentioned in the comments).

Apart from that, you need some form of conditional.

- if you're allowed to use the conditional, you can do it with recursion by removing one instance at a time.
- if you're allowed to use loops, you can loop until `y` is not found anymore.

The way you've coded it now, it will fail if `y` is not a part of `x`.

Think about

```
    System.out.println(without("checkers", "xy"));
    System.out.println(without("mymymy", "y"));
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it. You were setting a fixed length for the `secondHalf`, replacing it with `y.length()` fixes it.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[]args) {
    System.out.println(without("operation", "ra"));
    System.out.println(without("checkers", "ers"));
    System.out.println(without("checkers", "ch"));
}

public static String without(String x, String y) {
    int indexNumb = x.lastIndexOf(y);
    int lastIndex = x.length();
    String firstWord = x.substring(0, indexNumb);
    String secondHalf = x.substring(indexNumb + y.length(), lastIndex);
    return firstWord + secondHalf;
}

}
```

Comment: This fails, if `y` is not found. Furthermore, it removes only the last instance of `y`.

Comment: I think this is the best you can get without if statements.

Comment: In my answer, I pointed out some other options. Of course, all of them use some kind of condition. And this is also necessary for the corner cases I mentioned there.